jquery caught in unintentional loop with video time and select option
I am having issues with Video linking with  select options looping.
When the time of the video reaches it's video.currentTime, it changes the select value #chapters which in turn changes video.currentTime creating a loop.
This is my basic setup
video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
   if ((video.currentTime >= "0") && (video.currentTime <= "0.3")) {
       $("#chapters").val('ch1').change();
       $('div[id^="ch"]').hide(500);
       $("#ch1").show(1000);
       return false;
    }
    if ((video.currentTime >= "93") && (video.currentTime <= "93.3")) {
       $("#chapters").val('ch2').change();
       $('div[id^="ch"]').hide(1000);
       $("#ch2").show(1000);
       return false;
    } 
  });


$('#chapters').on('change', function() {
     if ($(this).val() == 'ch1'){
        video.currentTime = 0;
        return false;
     }
     if ($(this).val() == 'ch2'){
        video.currentTime = 93;
        return false;
     }
});

Then my html
<video style="max-width:100%; width: 900px;" controls autoplay id="element">
<source src="******.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video.
</video>

<select value="chapters" id="chapters">
<option>- - -</option>
<option value="all">ALL</option>
<option>- - -</option>
<option value="ch1">Section 1 - Intro - </option>
<option value="ch2">Section 2 - blah blah </option>

As seen, I have tried to use return false to get out of the loop, but it doesn't break it... Any ideas?

What are you trying to achieve with these 300 millisecond "chapters"... Is it supposed to loop?

Not sure if it's already solved, but the only possible thing I see where it might help is to:

Separate the change process from being inside the timeupdate process.

You want something like this logic below. Code is untested at this time.
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", on_timeUpdate);

function on_timeUpdate() 
{
    return false;
}

$('#chapters').on('change', function() 
{
     if ($(this).val() == 'ch1')
     { 
        video.currentTime = 0; 
        $('div[id^="ch"]').hide(500);
        $("#ch1").show(1000);
     }
     
     if ($(this).val() == 'ch2')
     { 
        video.currentTime = 93; 
        $('div[id^="ch"]').hide(1000);
        $("#ch2").show(1000);
     }
     
     return false;
});


Sorry, that would be my bad... the video.addEventListener is closed off, I just forgot to add the end brackets in my example
